# Respond to AJAX with Django template rendered

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I want to be able to return fully rendered templates to an ajax call. For example:

```
segment.html

<div class="swappable_segment" id="{{ id }}">
    {% for object in objects %}
        <li>Some text</li>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

views.py

def f(request):
    return SOMETHING
```

There should be ajax code such that when I press a button on a page, it swaps out the old div with a newly rendered div.

I know how to do the AJAX part, but I'm wondering what the function `f` should return. I'm thinking it should return an `HttpResonse` object with  JSON with the html of the new div, but I dont know how to actually render it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def f(request):

    [...] #logic here to get objects_list

    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('path/to/your/segment.html', {'objects': objects_list})
        return HttpResponse(html)
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut

Comment: I'll give it a try. Is there documentation for `is_ajax`? I've never seen that before

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax